# Integrating $\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c} \omega e^{ik\omega} d\omega$

Tags: integration

Integrating  $\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c} \omega e^{ik\omega} d\omega$

where $i^2 = -1$. I thought this would be relatively straightforward applying integration by parts, $\int uv' = uv - \int u'v$, where $u = \omega$, $u' = 1$, $v' = e^{ik\omega}$, $v=\dfrac{1}{ik}e^{ik\omega}$ but am going wrong somewhere...

$\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c} \omega e^{ik\omega} d\omega = \omega \dfrac{1}{ik}e^{ik\omega} - \dfrac{1}{ik} \int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c} e^{ik\omega}$

Factoring out the $\dfrac{1}{ik}$ and evaluating the integral between the bounds. However, this is not correct as the answer has $(ik)^2$ in the demoninator, but I cannot see what step of mine is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just haven't followed through. $$\frac{1}{ik}\int e^{ik\omega}\,\mathrm{d}\omega=\frac{1}{(ik)^2}e^{ik\omega}+C$$

Comment: oh man, when evaluating the second integral I just stuck the bounds in without actually integrating it.... Thanks!